# Linux - Download/extract Script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am looking to integrate a script with my control panel and am having issues as i am a novice scripter. What I would like to do is with 1 script download a file and extract it.

Example:

wget http://example.com/example.tar.gz

tar -xvzf example.tar.gz -C /

Do I need the following: #!/bin/bash at the start?

Any help would greatly help. Thank you.

Comment: Extracting the files to the root directory is usually a bad idea.

Comment: In fact, extracting any just-downloaded file anywhere except a newly created temporary sandbox directory leaves you open to various nefarious scenarios...

Answer (score 0):

Yupp, basically save this to myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -nv http://example.com/example.tar.gz
tar -zxvf example.tar.gz
```

then to execute it

```
./myscript.sh
```

More info about this here:
http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Comment: Working now with the info changed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `#!` at the beginning (called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) is used when your file is executed as a program. It tells the program loader what program to run the file with (/bin/bash in this case), so it is run using the command `/bin/bash script_name.sh`.

If the line is there, and the file has executable permissions, you can run it by double-clicking in the GUI or running `path/to/script_name.sh` in the shell.
Whether the line is there or not, you can always run it using `bash path/to/script_name.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic script to download and extract any `.tar.gz` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -qO- $1 | tar zxv
```

then do `./myscript.sh http://example.com/example2.tar.gz`